# Odoo - Compute unit price from subtotal and quantity

Tags: python, xml, odoo, purchase-order

I am trying to make make the subtotal column field editable and compute the unit price field by writing an onchange function for unit price that will be calculated by dividing subtotal by quantity.

This is my code so far:

```
class custom_unit_price(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'purchase.order.line'

    subtotal = fields.Float(compute='_compute_subtotal', store=True)
    price_unit = fields.Float(compute='_compute_unit_price', inverse='_set_unit_price')

    @api.depends('product_qty', 'price_unit', 'taxes_id')
    def _compute_subtotal(self):
        for line in self:
            taxes = line.taxes_id.compute_all(line.price_unit, line.order_id.currency_id, line.product_qty, line.product_id, line.order_id.partner_id)
            line.subtotal = taxes['total_excluded']

    def _inverse_subtotal(self):
        for line in self:
            if line.product_qty != 0:
                line.price_unit = line.subtotal / line.product_qty
            else:
                line.price_unit = 0.0

    @api.depends('subtotal', 'product_qty')
    def _compute_unit_price(self):
        for line in self:
            if line.product_qty != 0:
                line.price_unit = line.subtotal / line.product_qty
            else:
                line.price_unit = 0.0

    def _set_unit_price(self):
        for line in self:
            line.subtotal = line.price_unit * line.product_qty

    @api.onchange('subtotal')
    def _onchange_subtotal(self):
        if self.product_qty != 0:
            self.price_unit = self.subtotal / self.product_qty
        else:
            self.price_unit = 0.0

    @api.onchange('product_qty', 'price_unit')
    def _onchange_qty_or_price(self):
        self.subtotal = self.product_qty * self.price_unit
```

When I enter any amount in subtotal field, nothing happens. It reverts back to its original state (unit price * quantity). I want the unit price field to change when there is change in subtotal field or product quantity field.

Thank you.

Comment: I would highly recommend you not to do that. The subtotal is calculated from many places 
like what will happen when you add a discount It should affect the subtotal, 
Instead create a separate field that will do what you are trying it will be way more straightforward, and if your calc is correct, the subtotal value will be the same, i guess you are not planing to use discount feature